# About Roots of Polynomial Equation with Sympy in Python

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, polynomials

I need to study the roots of a polynomial equation using Sympy. This equation is obtained from a transcendental equation as the summary below:

a) In the original equation **P(L) + exp(-kL).Q(L) = 0** (**k** is a real constant) make the substitution **L = I.omega** (I is the imaginary unit). Here, **P** and **Q** are polynomials.

b) Computes the polynomial **F** defined by **F(omega) = |P(I.omega)|^2 + |Q(I.omega)|^2**

c) Find the roots of **F=0** and verify if these roots have positive values.

I wrote a code using Sympy to do this, but I am notable to find the roots.

```
# Modules
import sympy

# Parameters
beta = sympy.Symbol('beta', positive = True, real = True)
epsilon = sympy.Symbol('epsilon', positive = True, real = True)
delta = sympy.Symbol('delta', positive = True, real = True)
sigma = sympy.Symbol('sigma', positive = True, real = True)
gamma = sympy.Symbol('gamma', positive = True, real = True)
mu = sympy.Symbol('mu', positive = True, real = True)
psi = sympy.Symbol('psi', positive = True, real = True)
N = sympy.Symbol('N', positive = True, real = True)
B = sympy.Symbol('B', positive = True, real = True)
L = sympy.Symbol('L', positive = True, real = True)
tau = sympy.Symbol('tau', positive = True, real = True)

# Polynomiais P and Q
P  =  - B*L**3*beta*epsilon/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**3*beta*mu/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**3*beta*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**2*beta*delta*epsilon/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**2*beta*delta*mu/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**2*beta*delta*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*L**2*beta*epsilon**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*L**2*beta*epsilon*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**2*beta*mu**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**2*beta*mu*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*L*beta*delta*epsilon**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*L*beta*delta*epsilon*mu/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*L*beta*delta*epsilon*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*L*beta*epsilon**2*mu/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 3*B*L*beta*epsilon*mu**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*L*beta*epsilon*mu*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*L*beta*mu**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*L*beta*mu**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*delta*epsilon**2*mu/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*delta*mu**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*delta*mu**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*epsilon**2*mu**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*beta*epsilon*mu**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*epsilon*mu**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*mu**4/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*mu**3*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + L**4 \
      + L**3*delta \
      - L**3*epsilon \
      + L**3*gamma \
      + 2*L**3*mu \
      - L**2*delta*epsilon \
      + L**2*delta*gamma \
      + L**2*delta*mu \
      - L**2*epsilon*gamma \
      - 3*L**2*epsilon*mu \
      + L**2*gamma*mu \
      + L**2*mu*sigma*exp(-L*tau) \
      - L*delta*epsilon*gamma \
      - 2*L*delta*epsilon*mu \
      - L*delta*mu**2 \
      - 2*L*epsilon*gamma*mu \
      - 3*L*epsilon*mu**2 \
      - L*gamma*mu**2 \
      - 2*L*mu**3 \
      - delta*epsilon*gamma*mu \
      - delta*epsilon*mu**2 \
      - delta*gamma*mu**2 \
      - delta*mu**3 \
      - epsilon*gamma*mu**2 \
      - epsilon*mu**3 \
      - gamma*mu**3 \
      - mu**4 \
          
Q =   - B*L**2*beta*epsilon*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**2*beta*mu*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L**2*beta*psi*sigma**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L*beta*delta*epsilon*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L*beta*delta*mu*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      - B*L*beta*delta*psi*sigma**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*L*beta*epsilon**2*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*L*beta*epsilon*mu*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*L*beta*epsilon*psi*sigma**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*beta*delta*epsilon**2*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 3*B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*beta*delta*epsilon*psi*sigma**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*delta*mu**2*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*delta*mu*psi*sigma**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*beta*epsilon**2*mu*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 3*B*beta*epsilon*mu**2*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + 2*B*beta*epsilon*mu*psi*sigma**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*mu**3*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + B*beta*mu**2*psi*sigma**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) \
      + L**3*sigma \
      + L**2*delta*sigma \
      - 2*L**2*epsilon*sigma \
      + L**2*gamma*sigma \
      - 2*L*delta*epsilon*sigma \
      + L*delta*gamma*sigma \
      - 2*L*epsilon*gamma*sigma \
      - 4*L*epsilon*mu*sigma \
      - L*mu**2*sigma \
      - 2*delta*epsilon*gamma*sigma \
      - 2*delta*epsilon*mu*sigma \
      - delta*gamma*mu*sigma \
      - delta*mu**2*sigma \
      - 2*epsilon*gamma*mu*sigma \
      - 2*epsilon*mu**2*sigma \
      - gamma*mu**2*sigma \
      - mu**3*sigma

      
# Substitution :: L = I*omega
new_variable = I*omega
P_subs = P.subs(L, new_variable)
Q_subs = Q.subs(L, new_variable) 

# Polynomial F
F = sympy.Abs(P_subs)**2 + sympy.Abs(P_subs)**2   

# Roots of F
sympy.roots(F, omega)
```

When I run my code I received some error messages:

```
  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polyutils.py:211 in _parallel_dict_from_expr_if_gens
    monom[indices[base]] = exp

KeyError: Abs(B*beta*delta*epsilon**2*mu/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*delta*epsilon**2*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 2*B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*epsilon*omega**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*delta*epsilon*omega*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*mu**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*mu**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*mu*omega**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*omega**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*epsilon**2*mu**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 2*I*B*beta*epsilon**2*mu*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) - B*beta*epsilon**2*omega**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 2*B*beta*epsilon*mu**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 3*I*B*beta*epsilon*mu**2*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*epsilon*mu**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 2*I*B*beta*epsilon*mu*omega*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*epsilon*omega**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) - B*beta*epsilon*omega**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*mu**4/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*mu**3*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*mu**3*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*mu**2*omega**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*mu**2*omega*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*mu*omega**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*mu*omega**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*omega**3*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) - delta*epsilon*gamma*mu - I*delta*epsilon*gamma*omega - delta*epsilon*mu**2 - 2*I*delta*epsilon*mu*omega + delta*epsilon*omega**2 - delta*gamma*mu**2 - delta*gamma*omega**2 - delta*mu**3 - I*delta*mu**2*omega - delta*mu*omega**2 - I*delta*omega**3 - epsilon*gamma*mu**2 - 2*I*epsilon*gamma*mu*omega + epsilon*gamma*omega**2 - epsilon*mu**3 - 3*I*epsilon*mu**2*omega + 3*epsilon*mu*omega**2 + I*epsilon*omega**3 - gamma*mu**3 - I*gamma*mu**2*omega - gamma*mu*omega**2 - I*gamma*omega**3 - mu**4 - 2*I*mu**3*omega - 2*I*mu*omega**3 - mu*omega**2*sigma*exp(-I*omega*tau) + omega**4)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[108], line 1
    sympy.roots(F, omega)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polyroots.py:931 in roots
    F = Poly(f, *gens, **flags)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py:182 in __new__
    return cls._from_expr(rep, opt)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py:311 in _from_expr
    rep, opt = _dict_from_expr(rep, opt)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polyutils.py:368 in _dict_from_expr
    rep, gens = _dict_from_expr_if_gens(expr, opt)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polyutils.py:307 in _dict_from_expr_if_gens
    (poly,), gens = _parallel_dict_from_expr_if_gens((expr,), opt)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polyutils.py:216 in _parallel_dict_from_expr_if_gens
    raise PolynomialError("%s contains an element of "

PolynomialError: Abs(B*beta*delta*epsilon**2*mu/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*delta*epsilon**2*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 2*B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*epsilon*mu*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*epsilon*omega**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*delta*epsilon*omega*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*mu**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*mu**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*mu*omega**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*delta*omega**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*epsilon**2*mu**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 2*I*B*beta*epsilon**2*mu*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) - B*beta*epsilon**2*omega**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 2*B*beta*epsilon*mu**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 3*I*B*beta*epsilon*mu**2*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*epsilon*mu**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + 2*I*B*beta*epsilon*mu*omega*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*epsilon*omega**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) - B*beta*epsilon*omega**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*mu**4/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*mu**3*omega/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*mu**3*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*mu**2*omega**2/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*mu**2*omega*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*mu*omega**3/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + B*beta*mu*omega**2*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) + I*B*beta*omega**3*psi*sigma/(N*epsilon*mu + N*mu**2 + N*mu*psi) - delta*epsilon*gamma*mu - I*delta*epsilon*gamma*omega - delta*epsilon*mu**2 - 2*I*delta*epsilon*mu*omega + delta*epsilon*omega**2 - delta*gamma*mu**2 - delta*gamma*omega**2 - delta*mu**3 - I*delta*mu**2*omega - delta*mu*omega**2 - I*delta*omega**3 - epsilon*gamma*mu**2 - 2*I*epsilon*gamma*mu*omega + epsilon*gamma*omega**2 - epsilon*mu**3 - 3*I*epsilon*mu**2*omega + 3*epsilon*mu*omega**2 + I*epsilon*omega**3 - gamma*mu**3 - I*gamma*mu**2*omega - gamma*mu*omega**2 - I*gamma*omega**3 - mu**4 - 2*I*mu**3*omega - 2*I*mu*omega**3 - mu*omega**2*sigma*exp(-I*omega*tau) + omega**4)**2 contains an element of the set of generators.
```

How solve these errors?
Specifically, as (a) to find the roots of my polynomial F and **more important** as (b) to check if these roots are positive values?

Comment: Where is `pol_new` defined?

Comment: Sorry, @jared. I forgot one line in my code. Please, consider that pol_new is equal to F..

Comment: You can edit your question to fix it.

Comment: There are still undefined symbols. The code as shown does not work.

Comment: In any case the problem is straight-forward: `roots` expects a polynomial but your expression is not a polynomial because it has `Abs`.

Comment: Oscar, thank you for your appointment. Do you have any suggestions for my case? Regards.